# Как получить запись из .env

Tags: php, laravel

Добавляю в файл .env новое значение, как его получить в шаблоне или контроллере?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
env('ТВОЕ_НАЗВАНИЕ', 'ЗНАЧЕНИЕ ПО УМОЛЧАНИЮ'),
```

Answer (score 2):

laravel 5

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function()
{
    return getenv('APP_ENV') ?: 'production';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Все переменные, описанные в этом файле, будут автоматически доступны вашему приложения в суперглобальной переменной $_ENV и вы сможете использовать их везде в своем приложении.